# Optimize performance on SQL table - indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-server-2014

I have a table in my DB which contains 5 million records:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PurchaseFact](
    [Branch] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProdAnal] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Account] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Partno] [varchar](24) NULL,
    [DteGRN] [date] NULL,
    [DteAct] [date] NULL,
    [DteExpect] [date] NULL,
    [OrderNo] [bigint] NULL,
    [GRNNO] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [SuppAdv] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [Supplier] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [OrdType] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [UnitStock] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [OrderQty] [float] NULL,
    [RecdQty] [float] NULL,
    [Batch] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [CostPr] [float] NULL,
    [Reason] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [TotalCost] [float] NULL,
    [Magic] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Magic] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As you can see from the above - a `CLUSTERED INDEX` is being used on the `MAGIC` column which is a `UNIQUE` column.

Data retrieval time for the following `SELECT statement` is well over 8mins which causes reporting issues:

```
SELECT Branch,
    Supplier,
    ProdAnal,
    DteGRN AS Date,
    PartNo AS Partno,
    OrderNo,
    OrderQty,
    TotalCost,
    CostPr
FROM dbo.PurchaseFact src
WHERE YEAR(DteGRN) = 2016
```

Excluding the `WHERE clause` also doesn't make the query run any faster.
I have tried, together with the `CLUSTERED index` to include a `UNIQUE index` in the hopes that it would run faster but to no avail :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Unique_Index ON dbo.PurchaseFact ([Branch], [Supplier], [Magic]) 
INCLUDE ([ProdAnal], [Account], [Partno], [DteAct], [DteExpect], [OrderNo], [GRNNO], 
[SuppAdv], [OrdType], [UnitStock])
```

Is there any way I can optimize performance time on this table or should I resort to archiving old data?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many rows are returned for year 2016? Data transfer may take some time.

Comment: Could you add a persisted computed column to do that year calculation? You could then add a non clustered index on this field and include the others.

Comment: @jarlh - 1,6 million records being returned.

Comment: You may try index on DteGRN and  <=, >= predicates to select data within the year.

Comment: I see two issues: First, your original query is NOT using the index (and hence full table scan). Second, you are manipulating the year (the extraction of the YEAR part). I would suggest you change this and use instead `WHERE DteGRN >= '2016-01-01' and DteGRN < '2017-01-01'` (or the alternative `BETWEEN` format).

Comment: So one row in 3 are returned... An index may speed up a little but not much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your `where` clause:

```
WHERE YEAR(DteGRN) = 2016
```

If the table has 5 million rows, then this is going to return a lot of data, assuming any reasonable distribution of dates.  The volume of data is probably responsible for the length of time for the query.

One thing you can do is to rephrase the `WHERE` and then put an index on the appropriate column:

```
WHERE DteGRN >= '2016-01-01' and DteGRN < '2017-01-01'
```

This can then take advantage of an index on `PurchaseFact(DteGRN)`.  However, given the likely number of rows being returned, the index probably will not help very much.

The bigger question is why your reporting application is bringing back all the rows from 2016, rather than summarizing them inside the database.  I suspect you have an architecture issue with the reporting application.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - this most certainly helped speed things up. From 8:44mins down to 2:50mins.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, can't add comments.

To help improve performance further (if you can live with the UPDATE overhead), create a COVERING INDEX that INCLUDES only the columns in the SELECT part of the query.